# Refactoring the logic of a return value

Tags: c#

In my method I have something like this:

```
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(pa.Phone))
        {
            if (pa.Length != 10 && member == Schema.Phone.Name)
            {
                returnValue = new stuff;
            }
        }

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(pa.OtherPhone))
        {
            if (pa.OtherPhone.Length != 10 && member == Schema.OtherPhone.Name)
            {
                returnValue = new stuff;
            }
        }

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(pa.Fax))
        {
            if (pa.Fax.Length != 10 && member == Schema.Fax.Name)
            {
                returnValue = new stuff
            }
        }

        // even more similar ifs...

        // at the end of method: return returnValue;
```

How can I refactor this logic? 
Note that `new stuff` is always the same for all the `ifs`

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is better suited to Code Review.

Comment: If it is the same value for all the ifs, why do you need the ifs

Comment: This would be good to post to http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @DanHunex : because if none of the ifs is true, it will be null

Comment: @DanHunex: It is not the same value for all the ifs. Each time, another property is examined.

Comment: then initialize the returnValue before the ifs begin ...that will be the default value